# React / High chart / Stacked bar label for each block

Tags: reactjs, highcharts

I am trying to have stacked bar with different color as below.

I could achive bar as below however looking for -
1. label under each block and count.
2. On click on one of the block, color for rest of the blocks should be changed (should be same as hover behaviour)

Any suggestion and help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use stacked bar chart with enabled data labels:

```
    plotOptions: {
        bar: {
            stacking: 'normal',
            dataLabels: {
                color: 'black',
                enabled: true,
                y: 80
            }
        }
    }
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/wg46umjp/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.bar.dataLabels

Comment: Thanks, that helps. One small thing.. on click of of one block, can opacity of other blocks can be kept reduced? Or we need to handles it while passing series?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, please check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/dt54hf9j/